# If $G=\langle H,K\rangle$, then $G'=[H,K]$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, finitely-generated, characteristic-subgroups

> Let $H,K$ be two Abelian subgroups of a finite group $G$ such that $G=\langle H,K\rangle$. Show that $G'=[H,K]$.

**My attempt:** Ofcourse, $[H,K]\subseteq [G,G]=G'$. Conversely, let $x,y\in G$. It suffices to show that $[x,y]\in [H,K]$.

Since $G=\langle H,K\rangle$, there exists $a_i,b_i\in H\cup K$ such that $x=\prod_i a_i^{k_i}$ and $y=\prod_i b_i^{j_i}$. Thus $$[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy=\prod_i a_i^{-k_i}\prod_i b_i^{-j_i}\prod_i a_i^{k_i}\prod_i b_i^{j_i}.$$

---

I don't know how to proceed from here. If $H$ and $K$ were to commute with each other, then I could proceed, but since they're only given to be Abelian, I can't seem to use this hypothesis.

Comment: Should be $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$.

Comment: @Guest On Page 24 of Kurzweil and Stellmacher they define $[x,y] := x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$. Some authors define $[x,y] := xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$, but I have never seen your definition,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve using hints from @Cpc:

---

Let $x,y\in G$. Then there exists $u_i,w_i\in H\cup K$ such that $x=\prod_{i=1}^m u_i$ and $y=\prod_{i=1}^n w_i$. We proceed by induction on $m+n$.

**Base cases:**

- $m+n=1$. Then $[x,y]=1\in [H,K]$.
- $m+n=2$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $m=n=1$.
  If $u_1,w_1\in H$. Then $[x,y]\in [H,H]=1$, because $H$ is Abelian. Similarly, if $u_1,w_1\in K$, then again $[x,y]=1$. Next, if $u_1\in H, u_2\in K$, then $[x,y]=[u_1,w_1]\in [H,K]$. Lastly, if $u_1\in H, u_2\in K$, then $[x,y]=[u_1,w_1]\in [K,H]=[H,K]$.

**Induction step:** Suppose that $m+n\geq 3$. Without loss of generality, we may assume $m>1$. Then
$$[x,y]=[xu_m^{-1}u_m,y]=[xu_m^{-1},y]^{u_m}[u_m,y]\in [H,K];$$using the induction hypothesis and $[H,K]\trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $[xu_m^{-1}, y]^{u_m}[u_m,y]$?

Comment: @Cpc Oops, yes that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

This can be done in two steps.

- Prove $[H,K]\triangleleft \langle H,K\rangle$.
- Prove $G/[H,K]$ is abelian.

The first part is fairly straightforward.   The second can be done by induction.

Comment: I was able to show that $G'$ is the smallest normal subgroup containing $[H\cup K,H\cup K]$ but not $[H,K]$.

Comment: Then we've got a problem.

Comment: Can you help me proceed?

Comment: Only thing I can think of at this point is,  given the first part,  try to show that $G/[H,K]$ is abelian.

Comment: Use that $g\in G$ can be written as $g_1=u_1u_2\cdots u_m$, for $u_1,\dots u_m\in H\cup K$.  And try induction.

Comment: I've added an answer. Can you check it?